# Ошибка 401 при парсинге dns-shop. Авторизацию по cookie

Tags: python, парсер, requests, cookie, http-status-code-401

Если зайти через python requests, сайт выдает ошибку 401 (not authorized) независимо от того, какой user-agent установлен.
Если зайти через браузер, все ок. Открываем "инструменты разработчика", заходим в "Network", находим соответствующий запрос. Открываем Request Headers и видим огромный cookie. Если скопировать эти headers и вставить их запрос через python requests, сайт парсится ок. Но после выхода с сайта, повторные заходы через python requests снова выдают 401.
Я так понимаю, сервер присваивает этот cookie браузеру клиента при входе. Но сервер пускает браузер с первого раза, когда у браузера клиента еще нет cookie.

Как мне поймать этот сookie в python request?